# Is there a way to limit access to phoneNumber property in Firebase user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

According to Firebase doc, Firebase `User` has multiple properties and one of them is a phone number.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

All properties of `User` will be openly accessible to the user as long as he/she is signed in, regardless of the auth provider that the user used.

I worry that if my app uses both Email & Phone authentication, it is possible for attacker to obtain a user's phone number information just by using email and password.

For instance, an attacker who obtained various set of compromised email/password credentials could potentially log in to the app and be able to see full phone number, because all properties of `User` is accessible to the user as soon as the user is signed in. (assuming that the user linked EmailAuthCredential & PhoneAuthCredential).

Many apps and websites only display last few digits of phone number in order to protect user's identity in case an account gets compromised, and it seems like that is not possible with Firebase which can be a security issue. Is it possible to limit access to the one or some of the `User`'s properties, such as phoneNumber, from signed in user?

Answer (score 0):

If someone provides the credentials for a specific Firebase Authentication user, they gain access to the full profile of that user. The whole purpose of the user providing their credentials is to prove their identity and then allow them access to that profile. There is no way to shield (part of) the user profile from them, as it's for all intents and purposes *their* own profile.

If a user's credentials are stolen, you should assume all that user's data is at risk. If you need to deal with this within your application, the proper course of action is to disable the user's account, and provide them with an out-of-band way to reenable it once they reset their credentials.